# Viewing SSRS Reports in Mobile Device Using jQuery Mobile

Tags: sql-server, jquery-mobile, reporting-services

I need to develop a mobile app that can show reports from SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) already available in a server. How is this done using jQuery Mobile? Do I need extra components to achieve this?

Comment: Why would you specifically need jQuery Mobile? What have you tried so far / what solutions are you considering? It's quite a broad question you seem to be asking...

Comment: I am considering querying the SSRS web services manually. But I would like to do something close to a report viewer control in ASP.NET.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use the ASP.Net control? I just tried it on an ipad and it seemed to work ok.

Comment: My client is entirely written in JavaScript.